# To display the values of the other JSON using the id

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular6

**SCENARIO:**

I have 2 `JSON` files called `contacts` & `workers`:

**contacts**

```
  [
     {
      "name": "Jhon Doe",
      "gender": "Male",
      "workers": [
        "e39f9302-77b3-4c52-a858-adb67651ce86",
        "38688c41-8fda-41d7-b0f5-c37dce3f5374"
       ]
     },
     {
      "name": "Peter Parker",
      "gender": "Male",
      "workers": [
         "e39f9302-77b3-4c52-a858-adb67651ce86",
         "40665c50-ff74-4e81-b968-e127bdf1fe28"
        ]
     },
     {
      "name": "Mark Wood",
      "gender": "Male",
      "workers": [
          "ed780d15-428b-4bcd-8a91-bacae8b0b72e"
         ]
     },
     {
      "name": "Mary Jane",
      "gender": "Female",
      "workers": [
         "40665c50-ff74-4e81-b968-e127bdf1fe28",
         "ed780d15-428b-4bcd-8a91-bacae8b0b72e"
       ]
     }
]
```

**workers**

```
  [
   {
     "id": "e39f9302-77b3-4c52-a858-adb67651ce86",
     "name": "Alfy Odhams"
   },
   {
     "id": "38688c41-8fda-41d7-b0f5-c37dce3f5374",
     "name": "Allsun Suttle"
   },
   {
     "id": "ed780d15-428b-4bcd-8a91-bacae8b0b72e",
     "name": "Alvinia Ettritch"
   },
   {
     "id": "40665c50-ff74-4e81-b968-e127bdf1fe28",
     "name": "Ambrosi Lindenstrauss"
   }
 ]
```

I am displaying `contacts` like this:

[image]

**EXPECTED RESULT :**

I want to display assigned workers `name` for particular `contact` based on their `ID` like this:

[image]

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-ezawxb?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Or something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-p5vhg6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @JenyaG You can do more easily :) `return this.workers.find(w=>w.id==workerId).name`

Comment: I am getting this error inn the console: **ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

```
<tr>
    <td>Assigned Workers</td>
    <td>
        <div *ngFor="let cWorker of contact.workers">
            <div *ngFor="let worker of workers" [hidden]="cWorker!=worker.id">
              {{worker.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: really nice solution!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I am getting this error inn the console: **ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined** Stackblitz link **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-p5vhg6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html**

Comment: @Empty_Soul You might have forgotten to initialize the variables _workers_ and _contacts_. Check it.

Comment: I have  initialized avery variable, you can see the error in the **stackblitz** lin itself.Which i mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Nope. Confused between initializing and declaring. Replace `contacts;` with `contacts = [];` and `workers;` with `workers = [];`. P.S. I found another error in that demo, trying to assign an object into array variable. Take care of it in original code.

Comment: I got it thank you..:)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find your worker `name` based on the `id`. You need to create function inside of your `.ts` file like this

```
 findWorkerName(wid) {
    let obj = this.workers.find(({ id }) => id = wid)

    return obj ? obj.name : '';
 }
```

And your component file is like this

```
<h4>Contacts</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{contact.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>{{contact.gender}} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Assigned Workers</td>
        <td>
            <span *ngFor="let id of contact.workers let i = index">
            {{findWorkerName(id)}} {{i<contact.workers.length-1?',':''}}
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
             <hr>
  </div>
```

You could check with this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-edrhzn) demo. I have made changes in your code.